# Django template variables not working in django-social-widget

Tags: python, django

In following line while sharing the content to twitter, the template variable is not interpreted.

```
{% social_widget_render "twitter/share_button.html" href="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}" %}
```

instead of showing the actual url, it shows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code you write sends request.build_absolute_uri string itself, instead of it's value, because it's in double qoutes. You can try

```
{% social_widget_render "twitter/share_button.html" href=request.build_absolute_uri %}
```

Comment: I tried this myself in second attempt, didn't work. Now, it does.
Thank you

Comment: I was doing it. Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to it within next 10 mins